# How can I open port 2195 and 443 on my amazon ec2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have set up an Amazon ec2 server but I want to open port 2195 and 443.

I already added ports from security group in Amazon console.
When I listen port using

```
netstat -anltp | grep LISTEN
```

I got only two ports 23 and 80.

I also checked if ubuntu firewall is blocked or not.

Comment: What service do you have listening to the other ports? All you need to do is open it in the security group and in some cases the system firewall.

Comment: I opened all ports and allow ports 2195 and 443 from system firewall.i need to allow 2195 because want to implement push notification feature for iphone.

Answer (score 2):

After you add the ports in EC2 Security Group, they are ready to be used by any process. Restarting your EC2 instance is also not needed.

```
netstat -anltp | grep LISTEN
```

will start showing the new ports as soon as some process is started which LISTEN on them

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the e2 instance and check it and make sure you have the saved the security group settings after adding the new ports.

Comment: i already restart the ec2 server many times but result seems nothing.

Comment: Changes in `Security Group` do NOT require restart

Answer (score 0):

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport PORT_NO_U_WANTED_TO_OPEN -j ACCEPT

try this .

Answer (score 0):

you can disable iptables on ec2 because because there is security group on console to limit open port, but here my solution if you still want to using it:

manual edit file **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** with the following step

- flush iptables caches

  > iptables -F
- edit the file

  > nano /etc/sysconfig/iptables
- add you port and make sure the line like

  > -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
- and not

  > -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
- save and restart iptables

  > service iptables save
  >
  > service iptables restart